# Is it safe to use _UINavigationBarBackground class without risking app rejection by Apple?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, ios9

I want to modify the height of UINavigationBar when the app is in landscape mode. I followed the instruction I found at http://www.emdentec.com/blog/2014/2/25/hacking-uinavigationbar
In the solution _UINavigationBarBackground is being used which I assume is not directly accessible class.
So, will it be safe to use this or has someone faced a rejection from apple for using this class?

Comment: They don't have issues with the custom navigation bar or with height, since [gowalla app](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/43/38/17/43381735abf78ea580da3e0a7508e0a3.jpg) had customized nav bar. But the use of private api can land you in rejection zone.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely get rejected for using the private API, however there are ways to avoid detection (such as obfuscating the string you provide to `NSClassFromString`).